Can the US President and Vice President swap places to avoid 22nd Amendment?
This idea came to me from what Putin and Medvedev did back then in 2008-2009.
Can Donald Trump and JD Vance, for example, run in 2028, this time with Vance for president, and Trump for Vice President, after which:

One month after swearing in, Vance voluntarily steps down, allowing Trump to become President without being elected as President.
Trump then has to choose VP, and chooses Vance himself or somebody else.

Questions:

Would that be technically legal?
Would it be legal even if they openly state at rallies during election that Vance is a straw candidate whose only function will be to step down and clear the way for his VP Trump, and they intend to do this maneuver specifically to avoid the 22nd Amendment?
Would it be legal for the President Vance to be re-hired as the VP of his VP Trump once he's stepped down?


The term-limits on US and Russian President are different - the US constitution allows a US president to only serve two terms in office where as the Russian constitution bars a President from serving more than two terms consecutively (this is why Putin switched with the PM in the third term as he had already been President for 2 consecutive terms, and was barred from being a President again in the 3rd term).

It should be noted that in Russia they swapped two times (forth and back). However, if you ask for a dynasty kind of thing, surely Trump's family members could run next time.

No.
Per the 12th Amendment, if you are ineligible to be President, you also can't be Vice President.

"no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States."


I thought this question might have more to do with the 22nd making the individual ineligible to be elected president, but not ineligible to be president?

Thank you, that answers the question in that case, although what @bharring says might also make sense.

You're presenting this answer as a certainty, but it's actually highly contentious and there is plenty of legal opinion out there arguing both sides of the debate. Ultimately it's never been tested before and the answer will remain unknown until someone tries it, is challenged, and there is a court ruling.

@JBentley I haven't seen any particularly prominent legal scholars arguing that a two-term former president could be VP or that "constitutionally ineligible" doesn't include the 22nd amendment's prohibition on being elected more than twice.  Neither of the citations in the Wikipedia article seems particularly prominent.

@phoog Well, when I googled it before posting my comment, the first result was a journal article by Dan T. Coenen, a professor of constitutional law at the University of Georgia, arguing that a 2 term president can become a VP.

Inspired by @JBentley's link: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89963/eligible-vs-elected-in-the-drafting-of-the-22nd-amendment

Well, but suppose Donald Trump was selected as the Speaker of the House; and then both whoever was president and whoever was vice president resigned. Wouldn't he then become president?

@pigrammer: As I understand, Donald Trump would still have to be "Passed over" in the line of succession.

@pigrammer: yes, the SOTH can assume the office w/o being eligible for election, so long as he's eligible to be president (>35, citizen, etc).

The 12th would be irrelevant if it conflicted with the 22nd - a later Amendment overrides a prior Amendment. Either they are in harmony or the 22nd overrides the 12th. If the 22nd fails to forbid it, you can’t use the 12th to forbid it.

This particular end-run would not work. However, there are several other options:

Vance runs for president with Donald Trump Jr. as vice president. Once they take office, Don Jr. resigns, Donald Trump is appointed vice president, Vance resigns, and Donald Trump takes office as president.

Trump simply runs again in 2028, and SCOTUS rules that state secretaries of state don't have the authority to bar him from the ballot.

Trump makes it known that he will kill any secretaries of state that bar him from the ballot. According to SCOTUS, he is immune to prosecution for such a threat.

SCOTUS declares that the 22th amendment was improperly ratified.



The accepted answer seems to rule out #1 as writen, since presumably a president who had been elected to 2 terms would be equally ineligible to be "appointed" vice president as they would be to run as.

There is a major difference between the ineligibility due to term limits and the discussion about the issues around Jan 6th. There isn’t any question that I am aware of that would put any question of Trump’s eligibility in 2028

@JoeW Whether Trump's actions constitute "insurrection" is a legitimate question of debate. But the SCOTUS ruling that Trump was eligible to run in 2024 was not based on a finding that his actions didn't constitute insurrection. It was based on a finding that the 14th amendment isn't self-executing; that is, its restrictions on eligibility don't come into effect simply because the amendment was ratified, but rather require an act of Congress. SCOTUS could similarly declare the 22th amendment to not be self-executing.

@Acccumulation and it was done that way to avoid the question. The amendments regarding term limits are different than the 14th
